# Getting error while exporting data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, export-to-csv

I want to export data from SQL Server. The thing is that I can export some files, and some not.

To export I use SQL Server Management Studio. I choose SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as my data source. As destination I use a flat file destination. For example I can export theee types of file:

```
id,user,message,day
3,nick@gmail.com,message,monday
4,nick2@gmail.com,message2,tuesday
5,nick3@gmail.com,message3,friday
6,nick4@gmail.com,message4,sunday
```

But I cannot export something like this:

```
id,link
1,http://link.com
2,http://link2.com
3,http://link3.com
```

If I click preview everything seems to be fine. But when I try to export I'm getting this error:

> - Validating (Error)
>     Messages
>     Error 0xc020802e: Data Flow Task 1: The data type for "Destination - file_txt.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[Link]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.
>     (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - file_txt" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

The error details looks like that:

http://puu.sh/oJpDM/fcfbc9f2d4.png

Mapping looks like that:

http://puu.sh/oJpxn/2a7b2893a2.png

Do you guys have any idea what should I do?

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear. Use the right data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS - Flat file always ANSI never UTF-8 encoded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322642/ssis-flat-file-always-ansi-never-utf-8-encoded)

Comment: Wow, still no answer for this?

Comment: Please Select the UTF-8 and then Check the Unicode CheckBox ...Its Working For me